# PHP Sum 3 numbers equal exact number (Performance Issue)

Tags: php, performance

I am looking for a solution for sum up 3 numbers (inside an array - which is a given list of number) which is equal exact a number.

e.g

```
$sum = 172300
$array = array(11000,
1100,
2000,
1000,
4500,
83200,
3700,
29000
7000,
500,
1000,
2000,
20000
)
```

I had tried this solution, however, I set my PHP to execute_time to 6000 it also can't give me an result. 
https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76ee7de8-574f-4b0a-b078-8edff66d885d/view-source

I hope I can get an help to resolve this. I did try 3SUM solution, it also can't output the result.

My array list got around 100 values, means it is a lot of possible combination, any solution can help to reduce the executed time?

I need help in solve this..

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

To be more exact http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: One of the solutions is to use the backtracking algorithm.

Comment: Kanpsack problem is a two dimension problem, I think mine is just very direct, but my main issue is about performance, it takes too long to get the output.

Comment: Subset_sum_problem is exactly what you need, and it is a variation of the Kanpsack problem.

Comment: There are some improvements that you can do, share the code you created maybe we can help you with it.

Comment: Thanks. As I mention up there, I am using this solution. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76ee7de8-574f-4b0a-b078-8edff66d885d/view-source[/link] , I had sort the array before proceed, but it still too much executed time.

Comment: Sorry I was blind. The first problem I see is that you do not sort the elements. This is incredibly powerful.

Comment: Afterwards from what I understand you actually create a list with all the possible combinations of numbers and you check them all. That is incredibly not efficiently.

Comment: For example you have this array:  
$array = array(1,2,3,5,6,11,12);   
and you are looking for a total of 7. Why do you create all the combinations possible when you can just ignore part of the array (11,12).

Comment: Then you create all the possible arrays. After you create the following array  (1,6) you are still creating (1, 6, 11) (1, 6, 12) (1, 6, 11, 12) and summing them all. After you get 1,6 that is the exact sum you should ignore all the other arrays that contain those exact numbers.  

That is why the sorting is very powerful for you, it allows you to ignore a lot of arrays that otherwise you would still check.  

If you build it properly 100 numbers should not be a big problem.

Comment: you should build your algorithm like this.
Sort the array. Take the first number. Is it bigger then your sum? yes - you are done, no - continue. Pick the second number - is their sum bigger then your number? yes - you are done, no - pick another number. When you find a sum that is bigger then go back, unpick the last picked number and pick the following one.

Comment: It was very fun creating programs to solve problems like this in school :).

Comment: let's say I make the condition, won't bigger than my sum number. I exclude one condition, and the solution must be exact 3 numbers, I still get executed time error.. my array list is 81 numbers.

Comment: You changed it to be exactly this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM . In this case you should use that exact method to calculate it.

Comment: I did try change used the 3SUM, [Here](http://pastebin.com/dWFYh8zE) is the code. However, do you have any idea if I want to get closest match not exact match? Thanks!

Comment: At the beginning of the script do a  
$smallest_difference = $target;  
Then instead of calculating with =  
if ($a+$b+$c == $target){  
    echo $a,' + ',$b,' + ',$c;  
    exit;  
}  
do a 
$current_difference = abs($a+$b+$c-$target);
if ($current_difference < $smallest_difference){  
    $smallest_difference = $current_difference;
    $best_result = $a,' + ',$b,' + ',$c;
}  
  
At the end you will have the closest values in $best_result

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array. Take the biggest item, then look for the first item (starting from the second biggest) so that the two items add up to less than the target. Then, work your way from the smallest item up to see if there's a match. If not, move the second number down one and try again. Repeat this step until the second one is less than half of (biggest one - target). At this point, discard the biggest item, and repeat the entire process (minus the sorting).

You should find your solution in a much more optimal manner than random searching.

Comment: thank for your reply. what you means is do a sort in the array first. However, my sum number it will change, depend user input. The first number possible greater than the sum number. If I make the array less than 10 number, it will work, but if my array greater than 11, I got Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 600 seconds exceeded...

Comment: That's what [`sort`](http://php.net/sort) is for. It can sort thousands of elements in no time.

Comment: but the problem is sort, the bruce-force combination, it take like endless time...the link i post in my question, that one is OK for less than 10 numbers, however, if more than that, it got Maximum execution time error. I did try 6000 seconds, still got he same error... I am not good in data management. really appreciate your guys help.

Comment: I just ran a simple implementation that found `Result: 13715+13715+35529=62959 // Time taken: 0.40143394470215 seconds` with 1000 numbers to search with. [Here](http://pastebin.com/L3cpB8QG) is the code I wrote implementing the algorithm I gave in my answer.

Comment: Hi Kolink, thank you for your code. However, I did some testing on your code. It seem like not working 100%. [link](http://pastebin.com/Y3sWVFrS)

Comment: Yes, I realised this myself... Unfortunately I don't really have the time to debug it, but hopefully it can at least get you started.

Comment: Hi Kolink, thank you so much for your help. I have an idea how to start. Thanks!